# Ubuntu armhf 15.04 raspi2 - Tilda, terminal and keybinding at statup issue

Tags: tilda

I've started getting the following message when I boot up Ubuntu armhf 15.04 when I start Ubuntu on my raspi 2.

"the keybinding you choose for pull down terminal is invalid. please choose another"

I press close, and a Tilda screen pops up with a terminal in the background in the top left corner of my screen. In keybindings the pull down terminal is empty and nothing can be done there. I close tilda and then need to type exit to get rid of the terminal screen.

Quite annoying, how can I stop this and could anyone please let me know if there is a fix to get rid it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the problem occur in Ubuntu Mate 15.04. This is a simple way I found of fixing it (for new users such as myself).

1. When the Tilda 1 Config window appears, go to the Keybindings tab.
2. Click on "Pull Down Menu" at the top left of the window. A new dialogue will open with a place to click "Close": ignore that.
3. Press the key you wish to assign to Tilda's terminal. I used <kbd>F12</kbd> for this.
4. Click "Close".

As Christian stated, you can also remove it from the Startup, which I have also done.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be [fixed by now](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda/issues/82), try compiling the newest version.
Download the Source and take a look at the Instructions on [this page](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda).

But if you dont need or want Tilda, the easiest way to get rid of this error is to can disable it in the Startup Programs.